# Can't enter Ubuntu18.04 System when reboot ( dual system; seems some boot failure)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I've used Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 in my computer for about one and half years. Windows is on my HDD while Ubuntu is on another SSD. Three days ago I exited Ubuntu and entered Windows. After that when I backed to Ubuntu system，Only purple screen appeared. On the GRUB interface I tried to switch to other kernals (and their recovery modes), and all of them failed, showing some messages such as "failure reading sector" or "loading initial ramdisk".

After that I made a Ubuntu System Startup Disk and try to run boot-repair. But boot-repair application only gave me an error message.

> An error occurred during the repair
> Please write on a paper the
> following URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PncvgcRnyt/
> In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URI bootrepair@gmail.com
> ...

And from the URL above there are some details about the repair process. But I still don't understand where my problem really is.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please do not post pictures of text. Include all text in the body of the question. In this case the text in the picture is also too small to even read.

Comment: @David Thanks for your advice, I've modified my description.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly these problems are related with GRUB. Or if try this.

- Change the boot option from UEFI to LEGACY or from LEGACY to UEFI.
- If secure boot is disabled enable it or if it is enabled then disable it.

If nothing works, then its better to reinstall UBUNTU. (reinstalling the same version will give you an option to keep your files and install ubuntu).

Comment: Thank you. It will be nice to know reinstalling can preserve my data and files. However I don't find this option in the page "Installation type". It shows two options as "Erase Ubuntu 18.04.3LTS and reinstall" and "Erase disk and install Ubuntu".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that you can't install ubuntu by keeping your apps.                                 But you can install UBUNTU by keeping your documents.